# TimeoutException in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to using `selenium`. I am getting the following exception :

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py",
>   line 80, in until
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Following is my code snippet:

```
#time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#dr > option[value='_Unspecified']")))
#EC.presence_of_element_located
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea#ftx")))

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea#ftx")))
#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ftx")))
```

the last `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located`     is causing a `TimeOutException`. I tried several couple ways to locate the element. Also put in a time.sleep  statement. But I always get this error. Not sure how to fix it. All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: show us `HTML` for same

Comment: Please format your code as code and remove the bold. It just makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Please verify your element first.. may be it is inside any frame or iframe..